# Why is RegEx not picking up on the following segments within a string?

Tags: r, regex, string, ascii

I'm fairly new to R.

I'm working on a project that involves scraping from R and analyzing the content for sentiment and other variables. I'm using the RedditExtractoR package and the get_reddit() function to retrieve my data.

Here's an example of what a Reddit comment looks like:

> Honestly it\031s right up there with Out of the Woods and Cruel Summer for me so maybe that\031s saying more about me than it does about the songs \005\002 meh I\031m still going to bop

So as you can see, instead of punctuation like apostrophes, I'm seeing a backslash followed by 3 numbers. When I split the string using strsplit(comment, ""), the words and spaces are shown as separate characters, but the backslash and numbers show up as a single character as well (e.g.: "m", "e", "h", " ", "I", "\031", "m")

I've tried a couple of things to try to isolate this weird kind of string but nothing so far has worked. My attempts have included:

```
grepl("[\\\\]+[[:digit:]]+", comment)
grepl("^.*[\\\\]+[0-9]{3,}.*$", comment)
iconv(comment, from = "ASCII", to = "latin1", sub = "", toRaw = FALSE)
```

... and many more variations, all of which have returned the value FALSE. Additionally, when I split the string and save the "\031" as a variable, it returns class "character", and returns FALSE to any variation of grepl when the input is anything BUT the full "\031".

What can I try? I'm lost as to why regex wouldn't be able to pick out the backslash and digits.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is the expected result?

Comment: Let's be careful here: there is a difference between a literal backslash followed by three numbers, and a unicode symbol.

Comment: The end result that I hope to achieve is to remove all instances of a backslash followed by numbers from the text; the reason I'm using grepl instead of gsub right now is because it's easier to see whether the string has been detected or not.

Comment: I thought it might be something like unicode, but I have zero familiarity with different encoding systems... how would I go about removing unicode?

Comment: Actually, it isn't unicode (that would start with `\u` or `\U`), it's just an octal code for a character (see [`?Quotes`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html)). Looking some more ...

Comment: My *guess* is that something in the scraping process mis-identified those characters. `\031` is octal code for "end of medium" (http://www.asciitable.com/), which makes no sense to me ... I would have expected a "smart single quote", perhaps `\222`. Similarly, `\005\002` makes no sense to me. You can always do something like `gsub("\031", "'", gsub("[\002\003\005]", "", mystring))` for this example, ***wiping out*** most unrecognized octal characters (and replacing the single quote that I'm inferring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\031`, defined as a `"\031"` string literal in an R string, is a control character, called `END OF MEDIUM`. `\005` is an `ENQUIRY` char, and `\002` is `START OF TEXT`. They all belong to `Cc - Other, control` Unicode category class.

To check for these chars, you may use

```
grepl("\\p{Cc}", comment, perl=TRUE)
```

[R demo](https://ideone.com/oAidEo):

```
comment <- "Honestly it\031s right up there with Out of the Woods and Cruel Summer for me so maybe that\031s saying more about me than it does about the songs \005\002 meh I\031m still going to bop"
regmatches(comment, gregexpr("\\p{Cc}+", comment, perl=TRUE))
# => [1] "\031"     "\031"     "\005\002" "\031"    
grepl("\\p{Cc}", comment, perl=TRUE)
# => [1] TRUE
```

Comment: What would be a robust way of changing these \031s into actual apostrophes?

Comment: @Ludwig Replace them, `gsub("\031", "'", comment, fixed=TRUE)`. See [the R demo](https://ideone.com/TKAd7y).